# Add values to existing object for form select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set of value available to select in the form created this way;

```
@counties =   district.counties.map{|f| [f.name, f.id]}
```

However, i wish to add the values;

```
["Please select Sub-County", " "]
```

I have tried this with no success,

```
def update_counties
    district = District.find(params[:district_id])
    @counties =  {} << ["Please select County", " "] << district.counties.map{|f| [f.name, f.id]}
    @sub_counties =  {} << ["Please select Sub-County", " "] << district.counties.first.sub_counties.map{|f| [f.name, f.id]} 
    respond_to do |format|          
      format.js { }
    end    
  end
```

Assistance? please!

Comment: at first why these items in controller? use in views, and then use prompt in `select`

Comment: @nithin, this method is controlled by ajax calls. to update the select values.

Comment: that should not be a prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@counties = [["Please select sub-county", ""]]
@counties += district.counties.map{|f| [f.name, f.id]}
```